# PHP MYSQL numbers distribution

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

Can you imagine my problem ? .. For example I have infinity bowls. But into one bowl I am able to pull only 3 apples. So if somebody give me a 5 apples I have to put 3 apples into one bowl and 2 into second bowl. Same if somebody give me 7 apples, I put 3 in one, 3 in second and last one apple I put in one bowl.

And now I try to make this in php and mysql, apples is there as variable and bowls as rows in mysql.

```
if (isset($_POST[button])) {

    $apples = $_POST["apples"];
    $max_apples_in_bowl = 3;

    //if apple variable is ≤ 3 it is OK so i can write into table
    if ($apples <= 3) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `bowls` (`count_apples`) VALUES ('$apples');"; 
        mysql_query($query);
    }

    //but if not - i have condition that include cycle which write into table value 3 and deducted from the apple value 3. This cycle continue until apples ≤ 3 and then write a reminding part into table
    else {
        while ($apples <= 3) {
            $secondquery = "INSERT INTO `bowls` (`count_apples`) VALUES ('$max_apples_in_bowl');"; 
            mysql_query($secondquery);
            $apples = $apples - $max_apples_in_bowl;
            $thirdquery = "INSERT INTO `bowls` (`count_apples`) VALUES ('$apples');"; 
            mysql_query($thirdquery);

        }
    }
}
```

But it won't work. Of course if I put into `$apples` variable number between 0-3 everything is OK and it will write it into table. But if i put here 4 f.e. Nothing happens.

Can you help me with this guys?

Thank you.

Comment: create a while loop where it loops until the apple count is 0. Populate an array until you run out of apples subtracting 3 from apple count for each bowl you and until the apple count is 0. while( $apples  > 0 ) if $apples > 3 make bowl $apple - 3 if( $apples <= 3 ) add to bowl subtract $apple from number in bowl. In your if statement perform query.

Comment: @user2992063 try my answer i am sure you will get your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
$apples = $_POST["apples"];
$max_apples_in_bowl = 3;

$chunks = (int)($apples/$max_apples_in_bowl);
$remainder = $apples%$max_apples_in_bowl;

for($i=1; $i<=$chunks; $i++)
{
    $count_apples = $max_apples_in_bowl;
    $query = "INSERT INTO `bowls` (`count_apples`) VALUES ('$count_apples');";
    mysql_query($query); 
}

if($remainder>0)
{
    $count_apples = $remainder;
    $query = "INSERT INTO `bowls` (`count_apples`) VALUES ('$count_apples');";
    mysql_query($query); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`while ($apples <= 3)` should be `while ($apples > 3)`

Answer (score 0):

where your while statement starts you have the wrong signage. put in while($apples > 3). ;)

not just that try this

```
while ($apples > 3){
$seconddaryQuery = "INSERT INTO 'bowls' ('count_apples') VALUES ('$max_apples_in_bowl')";
$mysql_query($secondquery)
$apples = $apples - 3;
}
$thirdquery = "INSERT INTO 'bowls' ('count_apples') VALUES ('$apples')";
$mysql_query($thirdquery);
```

The logic that you had wouldnt have compensated for values bigger than six.
Try this it should work and let know how it goes so i can change something i fits wrong

Answer (score 0):

A simple `do ... while` could help here.

```
$apples=7;
$max_apples_in_bowl = 3;
do{
  $insert_value=$apples;
  if($apples>$_max_apples)$insert_value=3;    

  "INSERT INTO `bowls` (`count_apples`) VALUES ('$insert_value');";

  $apples-=$max_apples_in_bowl; //(7-3=4, 4-3=1, 1-3<0)
}while($apples>0);
```

P.S. Don't use mysql (it's depricated), Use mysqli